# Merge same key JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have a JSON data format like the below Vitamins , menrals , i need to merge same json keys array inside single array,

```
[
    {
        Vitamins: [
            "Please explain details about vitamins.",
            "Vitamin is a vitamin.:P:D",
            "7"
        ]
    },
    {
        Vitamins: [
            "i need more explanation about VitaminD. bcoz i'm new to medicine field ",
            "i don't know the ans.. :P",
            "7"
        ]
    },
    {
        Minerals: [
            "i need more info about Minerals!",
            "Minerals are found in soils",
            "8"
        ]
    }
]
```

but i need to change as , please help how to merge it

```
[
    {
        Vitamins: [
            {
                "Please explain details about vitamins.",
                "Vitamin is a vitamin.:P:D",
                "7"
            },
            {
                "i need more explanation about VitaminD. bcoz i'm new to medicine field ",
                "i don't know the ans.. :P",
                "7"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Minerals: [
            "i need more info about Minerals!",
            "Minerals are found in soils",
            "8"
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far? Please post the code of how you have tried to solve it.

Comment: You just need to format it right?

Comment: Yes Praveen , but these are i get dynamically so in case i can have 10 set of same keys and i need to merge it

Comment: @SarjanDesai It is perfectly valid. Why is it invalid?

Comment: Key `Vitamins` and `Minerals` are not in string format..For valid JSON both `key` and `value` are in string or digits....If you assign in object then it is valid Javascript object

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
first = [
  {
    Vitamins: [
      "Please explain details about vitamins.",
      "Vitamin is a vitamin.:P:D",
      "7"
    ]
  },
  {
    Vitamins: [
      "i need more explanation about VitaminD. bcoz i'm new to medicine field ",
      "i don't know the ans.. :P",
      "7"
    ]
  },
  {
    Minerals: [
      "i need more info about Minerals!",
      "Minerals are found in soils",
      "8"
    ]
  }
];
last = {};
for (var i in first) {
  if (typeof last[i] == "undefined")
    last[i] = [];
  last[i].push(first[i]);
}
console.log(last);
```

Check the console in JSBin example.

**JSBin: http://jsbin.com/guruxesaco/edit?js,console**

Comment: I need to merge the value of Vitamins inside same key , but this loop again forms the same json format

Comment: I don't understand. It does what you want. What key are you talking about? Did you check the console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I mean Vitamins as a key and Minerals as a key , Please check the output format which i have posted above .

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the answer to my question

```
   $t = [
    {
        Vitamins: [
            "Please explain details about vitamins.",
            "Vitamin is a vitamin.:P:D",
            "7"
        ]
    },
    {
        Vitamins: [
            "i need more explanation about VitaminD. bcoz i'm new to medicine field ",
            "i don't know the ans.. :P",
            "7"
        ]
    },
    {
        Minerals: [
            "i need more info about Minerals!",
            "Minerals are found in soils",
            "8"
        ]
    }
]

$result = array();

$s=0;



foreach($t as $t1=>$t2)
{

    foreach($t2 as $t3=>$t4)
    {

        $result[$t3][$s]=$t4;
        $s++;

    }
}
```

And the result is 
echo json_encode($result);

```
{
Vitamins: [
{
ques: "Please explain details about vitamins.",
ans: "Vitamin is a vitamin.:P:D"
},
{
ques: "i need more explanation about VitaminD. bcoz i'm new to medicine field...",
ans: "Vitamin D is found in Sun so please take sun bath daily."
}
],
Minerals: {
2: {
ques: "i need more info about Minerals!",
ans: "Minerals are found in soils"
}
}
}
```

Thanks for all your answers :)